# Access 2010 SQL query works fine by itself but not when linked to access db

Tags: sql-server-2005, ms-access-2010, linked-server

Access 2010 inventory db of items (item, location, qty etc...).
Linked SQL server 2005 tables of orders.

I've created an Access SQL query to retrieve a list of items for a particular order number. This runs fine by itself, but when I add links to my Access db, asking it for the location and qty, it only shows results for 1 item (last item)?

I feel like I'm missing something simple. I somewhat know my way around access but not so much in SQL and basically new to any programming languages.

Since I can't post photos yet I'll attempt to show examples of what is returned.

SQL Order query
**Headers** Order_no, Item_no
**Results** 00123, 77000; 00123, 77013; 00123, 77006; 00123, 77010; etc...

SQL order query with inventory
**Headers** Order_no, Item_no, Location, Qty
**Results** 00123, 77006, bin3, 24; 00123, 77006, bin4, 32; 00123, 77006, bin7, 21; 00123, 77006, bin14, 10.

Any ideas would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Question 1: "This runs fine by itself..." - do you mean here that you are running it against a local table?
Question 2: If the above answer is Yes, do both the local and linked tables have an identical number of rows rows containing identical data?

Comment: Thanks you in-directly answered my question. I discovered of the items returned from the SQL order query, only one of the items were in my inventory db. Never thought to manually check my inventory.